# iOS 7: How to force navigation bar of UINavigationController to be laid out as if status bar is showing even when status bar is hidden

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, statusbar

Is there a way to force the navigation bar of a UINavigationController to be laid out as if the status bar is showing even when the status bar is hidden? My motivation is to prevent the navigation bar for shifting when a navigation controller presents a view controller that returns YES for prefersStatusBarHidden. An example of this is when you look at an attached image in an email in the Gmail app.

Comment: You could subclass the navigation controller, and implement its `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, and size it there to your needs.

Comment: This doesn't quite work for me; the navigation bar's background needs to extend itself up beyond its frame to provide a background for the status bar. If, instead, I set the navigation bar's frame so that it underlaps the status bar, it works in portrait mode, but in landscape mode, the contents of the navigation bar become centered vertically in the bar, which makes the contents too close to the status bar. (Maybe it also seems to not realize that it is in landscape mode anymore.) Basically, I need to fight the internal maintenance the navigation controller and navigation bar are doing.